# How to remove blank lines from a char in C?

Tags: c

I have a simple c program that reads from a file and is supposed to print one word per line, remove all punctuations, and blank lines. I am stuck at detecting and removing blank lines.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    //char filename[15];
    char ch;


    f = fopen("index.txt","r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    ch = fgetc(f);
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        ch = fgetc(f);
        putchar (ch);
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\t'){
            printf("\n");
        }

        else if(ch == ',' || ch == '.'){
            printf("");
        }


    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I thought of removing the punctuations with this: 
else if(ch == ',' || ch == '.'){printf("");}

but its not working neither.

Comment: `<ctype.h>` has useful functions like `isalpha` and `isspace`.

Comment: I would kindly suggest to start by reading you own code... So many mistakes... Do you realize you're skipping the first character of the file? Do you realize you may output twice a new line? etc

Comment: This code is a *perfect* exercise to be run, step by step, in a debugger. It compiles, runs, and *mostly* tries to do what you want. Stepping through in a debugger will handily assist in determining the places it does *not* do what you want, and more importantly, *why*.

Comment: You can't do this processing one character at a time without remembering anything about previous characters. You need to detect when you're at the beginning or end of a word, and that requires some context. (You also need to define exactly what a "word" is.)

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? 
    `ch = 0;
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        ch = fgetc(f);
        if(ch== ' ' ||  ch== '\n' || ch== '\t' || ch== '\f' ch== '\v')
                printf("\n"); 
         else if (ch== ',' || ch== '.' )  { /*do nothing*/}
         else putchar(ch); 
   }`

Comment: The type of fgetc and EOF are both int.

Comment: "Cannot open file" is the canonical example of a bad error message. `if( ( f = fopen( path, mode)) == NULL ) { perror(path) ;...}`

Answer (score 2):

Among the things wrong in your code:

- You're skipping the first character with prejudice.
- The type of `ch` should be `int`, not `char`
- You should be consuming characters in two groups: those that are whitespace, and those that are not.
- You should be printing only characters from the second group (those that are not whitespace characters), further filtering them to *not* include `','` or `'.'`. Currently you're printing *everything* that is read (except the first character)

The result looks something like the following code (the content of my index.dat is the body of your question).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("index.dat","r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("index.dat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int ch = fgetc(f);
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        // skip any leading whitespace
        while (ch != EOF && isspace((unsigned char)ch))
            ch = fgetc(f);

        // on a non-white-space character
        if (ch != EOF)
        {
            while (ch != EOF && !isspace((unsigned char)ch))
            {
                if (ch != ',' && ch != '.')
                    putchar(ch);
                ch = fgetc(f);
            }
            fputc('\n', stdout);
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
I
have
a
simple
c
program
that
reads
from
a
file
and
is
supposed
to
print
one
word
per
line
remove
all
punctuations
and
blank
lines
I
am
stuck
at
detecting
and
removing
blank
lines
```

At least that is what you appear to be trying to accomplish

Comment: You left the 'removing all punctuation' as an exercise for the reader?  Running the program on its own source code leaves a lot of punctuation in the output.  I suppose to be fair you've done what the question does to eliminate 'all punctuation'. The `ispunct()` and `iscntrl()` and `isalnum()` functions from `<ctype.h>` could be useful.  The shell command `tr -cs 'A-Za-z0-9_' '\n'` can also be quite useful; it is succinct, if nothing else.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That was the intended goal , i.e. target-filter out any periods or commas as the OPs code seemingly desired. I concur, a blanket filter printing only `isalnum` would probably have been the full monte, but I wanted the OP to concentrate on the loops and the location where, what punctuation was being removed, was actually being done. Hopefully it doesn't differ too much from their code so as to best understand the key  differences; especially the loop control.0